# How to retrieve the information regarding $a$, from $a^\#$, for $a \in {^\omega\omega}$?

Tags: set-theory

So in a proof of a theorem in Kanamori's book, we first assume that $\forall a \in  {^\omega\omega}(a^\# \text{ exists})$ and then we have two reals $a, b$ and we code them through $c$ and we want to work with $L[a]$ and $L[b]$ in $L[c^\#]$. So naturally I wanted to show that $c \in L[c^\#]$ and go about my way. But here I come to a problem. Let me give some context first.

---

First there is this theorem:

> Theorem. $0^\#$ is absolute for transitive $\in$-models $M$ of ZF such that $\omega_1 \subset M$ in the following sense:
>   $$M \models \ulcorner \text{There is an EM blueprint satisfying (I)-(III)}\urcorner \text{ iff } 0^\# \in M, $$
>   in which case $M \models \ulcorner 0^\# \text{ is the unique EM blueprint satisfying (I)-(III)} \urcorner$. 
>   [Here the conditions $\text{(I)-(III)}$ are the wellfoundedness, unboundedness and remarkability properties of $0^\#$]

So this theorem is proved by constructing a $\Pi^1_2$ formula which defines the singleton $\{0^\#\}$ and by shoenfield absoluteness this proves the above theorem. For $a \in {^\omega\omega}$, Kanamori says that the exact same procedure above, gives us the absoluteness of $a^\#$ for models that contain it.

---

But there is a small twist to it that he doesn't mention. When I tried doing this myself to verify his claim, I realized that the above $M$ must also contain $a$ and at the time I didn't think much of it since it didn't matter. But now I am dealing with $L[c^\#]$ and I need to either refine the version of the theorem which I tried proving which required both of $c$ and $c^\#$ to be in $M$. Or more directly, show that we can construct $c$ from $c^\#$ in an explicit way.
So my question ultimately boils down to: How can we show that $c \in L[c^\#]$?
Because of the inherent complexity of this subject to a beginner like me, I would really appreciate any hints or remarks.

---

Edit I: 
To clarify, the reason for the fact that removing the base assumption $c \in M$, from the theorem would work is that then by $c^\# \in M$ we could trivially get to the fact that the EM blueprint for $L[c]$ exists and that would imply that $c \in M$.

Comment: Normally when you say that you code two reals into a single one, you're thinking about something like even/odd coordinates. And then it's easy to show that if $c\in M$, then $a,b\in M$ as well.

Comment: @Asaf, I know, but we are working in $L[c^\#]$. If we show that $c \in L[c^\#]$, then what you're saying completes the picture. But this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: Isn't this sort of the same proof as showing that every constructible real is recursive in $0^\#$?

Comment: @Asaf, I actually don't know what "being recursive in $0^\#$" means. If you mean recursive as being $\Delta^0_1(0^\#)$, again I only know this definition for sets of reals. If what you're saying might resolve the issue, could you please give me a reference so I can study up on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful about the structure in question! A sharp of a set $a$ doesn't just code the theory of $L[a]$ (plus indiscernible), but rather the *expansion* of this structure by a constant symbol naming $a$ (look carefully at the definition on page $110$).

So the real in question is built right into the structure whose blueprint our sharp is coding: our theory talks directly about it.

Comment: Yeah exactly, but since the real is built into the language, and the formula that Kanamori builds, defines $a^\#$, in this expanded language, we should require $M$ in the theorem to have $a$ as an element. Also when I tried writing the respective defining formula of $a^\#$, I had to use $a$ itself as a parameter, so the $M$ in question should have $a$ as an element.

Comment: @ShervinSorouri But since our real $c$ is coded directly into it's sharp, as soon as we have that sharp we can reconstruct the real. E.g. maybe our numbering of formulas is such that the $2 ^n$th formula in the sharp-building language is "$n$ is in $c$." Then the set of $n$ such that $ 2^n$ is in $c^\#$ is in $L[c^\#]$ by separation - remember that $L[x]$ satisfies full ZFC for every $x$ - but that's just $c$ itself. So $c$ is indeed in $L[x]$. (Indeed, as Asaf said its even computable relative to $c^\#$, which is a *vastly* stronger fact.)

Comment: Oh well, that completely resolves the issue, thanks! I think I should really get used to this "if it isn't working, just fix your definition." mentality. But it gets me everytime...

Comment: I was pointing out the part which you pointed out that we can fix our enumeration of our formulas, so that the $2^n$th formula is the one saying whether $n$ is in $c$ or not.

Comment: I know. It was just a small and harmless joke. Sorry.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misunderstood. :)